# Add a dynamic action to a report when next button is pressed

Tags: oracle-apex

How can i execute a dynamic action when i click in the button of a report to change to another page of vale ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the report template so that it assigns an ID to the next and previous buttons.  For example:

```
Next Page Template:
-------------------
<a href="#LINK#" class="t20pagination" id="#REGION_STATIC_ID#next">
#PAGINATION_NEXT# &gt;</a>

Previous Page Template:
-----------------------
<a href="#LINK#" class="t20pagination" id="#REGION_STATIC_ID#previous">
&lt;#PAGINATION_PREVIOUS#</a>
```

Then give your report region a Static ID e.g. 'MYREP'.  The next and previous links will then have IDs 'MYREPnext' and 'MYREPprevious'.

You can now create dynamic actions referencing those IDs as DOM objects or jQuery selectors.

Be sure to set the dynamic action's Event Scope to "live" so that the actions still work after the report has been refreshed due to pagination.